# Most efficient way to add a column to a MySql UNIQUE KEY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with a production database on a table that has > 2 million rows, and a UNIQUE KEY over col_a, col_b.

I need up modify that index to be over col_a, col_b, and col_c.

I believe this to be a valid, atomic command to make the change:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
  DROP INDEX `unique_cols`,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_cols` (
    `col_a`,
    `col_b`,
    `col_c`
  );
```

Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Is this a MyISAM or InnoDB table? It matters for the purposes of locking. And when you say "most efficient" what do you mean? Taking the least time? Or locking the least?

Comment: I'm mostly worried about how long the locks are held.

Comment: Is it an Innodb or MyISAM table? And what version of MySQL? These are important for determining how it will lock.

Comment: It's InnoDb, and version 5.7.14 (technically it's a Google Cloud SQL server, gen2).

Comment: Also.... why was this downvoted?

Comment: Also, I think I was overly worried about the cost of this. I cloned the original DB, and the unloaded clone finished the index changes in < 14 seconds.

In the process, I learned that our DB servers have WAY more ram than I thought (208G), which is probably why this was so quick.

Answer (score 2):

**I'm not certain that the following way is the best way for you. This is what worked for us after we suffered a few database problems ourselves and had to fix them quickly.**

We work on very large tables, over **4-5GB in size**.

Those tables have **>2 million rows**.

In our experience running any form of alter queries / Index creation on the table is dangerous if the table is being written to.

1. So in our case here is what we do if the table has writes 24/7:

   - Create a new empty table with the correct indexes.
   - Copy data to the new table row by row, using a tool like Percona or manually writing a script.

This allows for the table to use less Memory, and also saves you in case you have a MyISAM table.

2. In the scenario that you have a very large table that is not being written to regularly, you could create the indexes while it is not in use.

   - This is hard to predict and can lead to problems if you've not estimated correctly.

In either case, your goal should be to:

- `Save memory / load on the system.`
- `Reduce locks on the tables`

The above also holds true when we add / delete columns for our super large tables, so this is not something we do for just creating indexes, but also adding and subtracting columns.

Hope this helps, and anyone is free to disagree / add to my answer.

Some more helpful answers:

> - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54211/adding-index-to-large-mysql-tables:
>
> https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54214

- https://serverfault.com/questions/174749/modifying-columns-of-very-large-mysql-tables-with-little-or-no-downtime
- [most efficient way to add index to large mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685512/most-efficient-way-to-add-index-to-large-mysql-table)

Comment: Hi Someone downvoted my answer, please do let me know what I said that was wrong, so that we can improve as well. :)

Comment: Wild guess (didn't down-vote anybody myself), the "This is not the correct way to things, this is how we do things" sounds a little arrogant.

Comment: Oh i'm so sorry, I didn't say that to be arrogant. Let me change it. Didn't realise it sounded offensive. Sorry to anyone who read that. @AdrienBrunelat Please do let me know if this version is better.